# What does -1 in "ls -1 path" mean?

Tags: bash, shell, glob, ls

I am looking at some shell code that is meant to get the count of the number of files in a directory. It reads:

```
COUNT=$(ls -1 ${DIRNAME} | wc -l)
```

What does the `-1` part mean? I can't find anything about this in any other questions, just passing references to iterating over files in a directory which isn't what I am looking at. Also, removing it from the command seems to have no effect.

Comment: Emit one line of output per file.

Comment: ...which, yes, is the default when output is not to a terminal, but explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ah, that makes sense, thanks. Explains why nothing changes when I remove it.

Comment: BTW -- see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html -- all-caps environment variable names are reserved; names with lowercase characters should be preferred for application use. Granted, you're not necessarily `export`ing `COUNT`, but shell variables and environment variables share a namespace (a shell variable will automatically overwrite/modify any like-named environment variable), so lowercase names should be preferred by convention.

Comment: BTW -- see http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=COUNT%3D%24%28ls+-1+%24%7BDIRNAME%7D+%7C+wc+-l%29 (you can click through to get to the nesting level you care about, including describing the `-1` argument to `ls`).

Comment: ...http://shellcheck.net/ is also your friend (will find unquoted-expansion bugs, f'rinstance).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the links - explainshell seems super useful - bookmarked! Unfortunately I don't have full control over the script so not much I can do about the uppercase/lowercase variables right now. I'll keep it in mind for the future though.

Comment: ...also, see BashFAQ #4, which is almost directly on-point: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004

Comment: ...in general, btw, "test what happens when I change this" is a dangerous way to do things in bash -- there are lots of best practices around correctly handling corner cases, so deviating from them can make for code that looks fine but is subtly buggy (sometimes in security-impacting ways) only in situations one may not think to test.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user is too lazy to RTFM.

Comment: @Jens you're not wrong. I have never seen a numeric as a flag before this, so I just assumed it was something very obscure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
COUNT=$(ls -1 ${DIRNAME} | wc -l)
```

...is a buggy way to count files in a directory: `ls -1` tells `ls` not to put multiple files on a single line; making sure that `wc -l` will then, by counting lines, count files.

Now, let's speak to "buggy":

- Filenames can contain literal newlines. How a version of `ls` handles this is implementation-defined; some versions could double-count such files (GNU systems won't, but I wouldn't want to place bets about, say, random releases of `busybox` floating around on embedded routers).
- Unquoted expansion of `${DIRNAME}` allows the directory name to be string-split and glob-expanded before being passed to `ls`, so if the name contains whitespace, it can become multiple arguments. This should be `"$DIRNAME"` or `"${DIRNAME}"` instead.

...also, this is inefficient, as it invokes multiple external tools (`ls` and `wc`) to do something the shell can manage internally.

---

If you want something more robust, this version will work with all POSIX shells:

```
count_entries() { set -- "${1:-.}"/*; if [ -e "$1" ]; then echo "$#"; else echo 0; fi; }
count=$(count_entries "$DIRNAME") ## ideally, DIRNAME should be lower-case.
```

...or, if you want it to be faster-executing (not requiring a subshell), see the below (targeting only bash):

```
# like above, but write to a named variable, not stdout
count_entries_to_var() {
  local destvar=$1
  set -- "${2:-.}"/*
  if [[ -e "$1" || -L "$1" ]]; then
    printf -v "$destvar" %d "$#"
  else
    printf -v "$destvar" %d 0
  fi
}
count_entries_to_var count "$DIRNAME"
```

...or, if you're targeting bash and don't want to bother with a function, you can use an array:

```
files=( "$DIRNAME"/* )
if [[ -e "${files[0]}" || -L "${files[0]}" ]]; then
  echo "At least one file exists in $DIRNAME"
  echo "...in fact, there are exactly ${#files[@]} files in $DIRNAME"
else
  echo "No files exist in $DIRNAME"
fi
```

---

Finally -- if you want to deal with a list of file names too large to fit in memory, and you have GNU `find`, consider using that:

```
find "$DIRNAME" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '\n' | wc -l
```

...which avoids putting the names in the stream at all (and thus generates a stream for which one could simply measure length in bytes rather than number of lines, if one so chose).

Comment: Will you explain the bugginess and propose the safe way to do it?

Comment: Thanks. I observe that if string represented by `${DIRECTORY}` is very long, then in extreme cases, you might run into problems because the names are too long. I note that you can set longer argument lists with `set --` than you can process with a subsequent external command: `set -- $(perl -e 'for $i (1 .. 1000) { printf "%.5d-%s.txt\n", $i, "ABC" x 256; }');
echo $#;
echo "$@" | wc;
al "$@" | wc`
On Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite, this yielded `1000` (from `echo $#`), `1    1000  779000` from `echo "$@" | wc`, and `argument list too long` from processing `al | wc` (followed by 3 zeros from `wc`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, since the argument list is never being passed to an external command, it's not subject to the limitations present in execve() here; rather, one has only the same memory-use limitations present for setting any other shell variable(s).

Comment: On my machine, `al` is an external program, actually in C but equivalent to `printf "%s\n" "$@"` (`al` for 'argument list', listing each argument on its own line).  It stands in for an external program you choose: `cat`, for example, or `ls`.  In this example, you're pretty much safe because you're not invoking external programs.  In other contexts, the `$1/*` notation might be problematic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ...makes sense. In any event -- I'm a little unclear, from a cursory read of your example, as to whether it purports to demonstrate that a list of names exists that can be stored in memory with `set --` but not in a variable with `array=( ... )`. Does it in fact attempt to support that claim?

Comment: I was not making claims w.r.t arrays, nor comparing arrays to `set --` argument lists.  In fact, in a sense, I was validating that what you did would work even in extremis, but raising the spectre (a day early — since tomorrow is Halloween) that other operations doing something similar could run into issues.  (FWIW: `array=( "$@" )` added after the `set --` did not cause problems; `echo "${*array[@]}"` yielded 1000, as would be expected.)

Comment: To add to this tour-de-force, consider using `${1:-.}` to default to the current directory in `count_entries`, and to add `${1:-.}/.*` to get hidden files as well.

Comment: @chepner, hmm. Adopting the former; tricky thing with the latter is that it could double-count, depending on the shell's initial state (whether we're hiding dotfiles to begin with).

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Charles Duffy's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33445417/45375):

<sup>There's one edge case his answer doesn't cover: if the first directory entry happens to be a *broken symlink*, testing for glob expansion with `-e` is not enough, given that Bash always applies the existence test to a symlink's *target* - which in the case of a broken symlink doesn't exist by definition. In other words: for a broken symlink, `-e` will indicate *false*, even though the link *itself* exists. A fully robust solution must therefore use something like `[[ -e "$1" || -L "$1" ]]`

(`-L` tests if its argument is a symlink, whether broken or not.)</sup>

Here's a slightly **shorter `bash` alternative** (uses a subshell):

```
count=$(shopt -s nullglob; entries=(*); echo "${#entries[@]}")
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` ensures that the pattern expands to the empty string if nothing matches.
- `entries=(*)` collects all matches (in the current dir.) in an array
- `echo "${#entries[@]}"` output the element-array count.
- Since no external utilities are involved, this command is *not* subject to the `getconf ARG_MAX` limit, so should work with large directories.

Note that whether the above counts *hidden* (`.*`) items as well depends on the state of the `dotglob` option.
It is easy however, to build fixed hidden-items-included-or-not logic into the command:

**Explicitly *include* hidden items:**

```
count=$(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; entries=(*); echo "${#entries[@]}")
```

**Explicitly *exclude* hidden items:**

```
count=$(shopt -s nullglob; shopt -u dotglob; entries=(*); echo "${#entries[@]}")
```

---

It's possible to **wrap all of the above in a flexible function**:

```
countEntries [<dir>] ... counts based on current state of the `dotglob` option
countEntries <dir> 0 ... counts non-hidden entries only
countEntries <dir> 1 ... counts all entries, including hidden ones
```

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# SYNOPSIS
#   countEntries [<dir> [<includeHidden>]]
# DESCRIPTION
#  <dir> defaults to .
#  <includeHidden> default to the current state of `shopt dotglob`;
#  a value of 0 explicitly EXcludes, 1 explicity INcludes hidden items.
countEntries() ( # Run entire function in subhell.
  local dir=${1:-.} includeHidden=$2 entries
  shopt -s nullglob
  case $includeHidden in
    0) # EXclude hidden entries
      shopt -u dotglob
      ;;
    1) # INclude hidden entries
      shopt -s dotglob
      ;;
    # Otherwise: use *current state* of `dotglob`
  esac  
  entries=("$1"/*) # Collect in array
  echo "${#entries[@]}" # Output count.
)
```